# Recursive mysql query for checking user permisison

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

I have 3 tables:

1. role

   ```
   id | name   | parent_id
   -----------------------
   0  | user   | null
   1  | admin  | 0
   2  | manager| 0
   3  | ceo    | 1
   ```

where role.parent_id references role.id (example: admin inherits from user)

1. action

   ```
   id | name   |
   -------------
   0  | create |
   1  | delete |
   2  | update |
   3  | reset  |
   ```
2. role_action

   ```
   role_id | action_id |
   ---------------------
   0       | 0         |   (user can create)
   1       | 2         |   (admin can update)
   2       | 1         |   (manager can delete)
   3       | 3         |   (ceo can reset)
   ```

Because ceo inherits from admin and admin inherits from user, ceo should be able to create, delete and reset.

How would a write a recursive query to list ALL actions that can be performed by the ceo (or admin etc)?

In case of ceo, sample output would be:

```
    ceo  | create |
    ceo  | delete |
    ceo  | reset  |
```

Comment: Show same sample output. because i have some doubt about it. do you want show the action of ceo or ceo and parent of ceo and child of ceo ah?

Comment: @Sathish I would like to show the actions of ceo and parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
select 'ceo' as name,t1.name as dd from role_action t2 
inner join 
(
select id,name,@pv:=pid as 'pid' from
(select id, name,pid from role
order by case when name='ceo' then '0' else 1 end,
 pid desc) 
as t
join
(select @pv:=3)tmp
where id=@pv) as t on 
 t2.id=t.id
inner join action t1 on t1.id=t2.aid
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0b49a/18)

Comment: What's the difference between this query and the one you posted earlier?

Comment: I don't think this query would work because in the SQL Fiddle, you've mapped all of ceo's actions in the user_actions table. Where as in my example, i've only mapped one action that is specific to that user.

Comment: i did not understand your concept. do you want to show `ceo` action and parent of `ceo` action and parent of parent `ceo` action right ah?

Comment: If ceo's parent is admin and admin's parent is user, So, i want to list all actions of ceo and that would include all actions of admin and users as well. So, you don't have to separately map an action for ceo if hat action is already assigned to one of it's parent roles. I hope that makes it clear.

Comment: That looks good man. I'll try to understand what that query's doing by myself, but I might ask you to help me understand that query better If I can't. (If that's ok)

Comment: `select id,name,@pv:=pid as 'pid' from
(select id, name,pid from role
order by case when name='ceo' then '0' else 1 end,
 pid desc` this query use to find the parent and child. using desc order for get all parent id get correctly because its search the next records only.

Comment: @Chanthu You have enough reputation you could start using voting system as well.. :)